# What are these LED power supply plugs called?

Tags: led, connector, cables

New LED lamps made in China have fancy new connectors and I'm searching for the IEEE official name (or whichever authority names them). I need to order male and female ends that can be opened to expose wiring screws inside or soldering posts.

According to Power Brick it's probably 20V DC. The wire looks like 24 gauge? Let's call them thin speaker wires. The LED lamp draws ~7 watts.

Here's what the male plug looks like next to a dime:

[image: male end]

Here's what the female receiver looks like next to a standard USB plug:

[image: female end]

My goal is to buy 100 feet of speaker wire and make a 35 foot extension cable and a 25 foot extension.

A nice thin wire pair will run across the living room baseboards nicer than 14 gauge 120VAC cable.

Comment: Plugs like that aren't necessarily named by any authority.  They can be completely proprietary.  Having said that, if they're showing up on a lot of different brands, there's a chance that there's a standard, or at least a lot of companies kinda-sorta copying each other.  There's a slimmer chance that you can get parts in the West -- but you can try.

Comment: @TimWescott Did I mention they were made in China? Alibaba (spelling?) would probably sell me 100 at a time, if they are available!  Oh well can always dial back the clock to the 1970's, cut the wire, splice in 25 feet of speaker wire and use black electric tape over the pieces.

Comment: IKEA uses those for one of their LED table lamps

Comment: don't use electrical tape ... use heatshrink tubing

Comment: @jsotola I bought these from Structube today. They are like IKEA but more downtown cozy and less far out strip mall superstructure. I don't recall heatshrink tubing in the 1970's but they did have hair dryers that probably work on it for disco hair-doos.

Answer (score 4):

These look like DIN loudspeaker plugs. Odds are you could find some extension cords for those too!

I'm not sure how would you still source them, these new connectors aren't very new at all, and seem to be quite rare these days. One can still apparently find these listed on our favourite auction sites and the like as B&O connectors, as the brand still seems to use those. There also were 3- and 4-pin versions, but those now seem to be much, much more obscure!

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_connector#Loudspeaker_connector):

[image]

(Image taken from [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Speaker_din_male_and_female.jpg))

Comment: In the spirit of your last name -- Purrfect!

Comment: The males are cheap but the females are expensive: https://www.amazon.co.uk/electrosmart-Speaker-Loudspeaker-Cable-Connections/dp/B00512QE4I

Comment: Sssh, this might be off-topic for this site, but how about this kit? Still fairly expensive for two connectors, but what can you do... https://www.amazon.co.uk/Bandridge-2-Pin-Male-Female-Connector-Black/dp/B0015YYOQ6

Or these: https://www.ebay.com/itm/253105995451 and https://www.ebay.com/itm/322628216974

Comment: Yeah 3 pounds 70 pence is horrendous when converted to CAD or even USD for that matter. ebay.com has lots of vendors from China with free shipping (UK usually charges me tons for shipping). Funny thing about these connectors is they are for non-polarized applications but they have polarized matching design to them...

Comment: They are polarized as there also were 3- and 4-pin versions of these meant for stereo applications (which is why the other semicircle of the connector seems to be oddly left unused on the circular versions). The third and fourth pins were offset, so one couldn't easily plug it in the wrong way around. Sadly I cannot find any pictures nor datasheets for those as of now; I may update the answer later.

Comment: Yeah I can buy 10 females for $3.04: https://www.ebay.com/itm/10-Pcs-2-Pin-DIN-Speaker-Plug-2-Pin-Plug-Hifi-Loudspeaker-Cable-Solder-Connector/113171612545?hash=item1a598dc381:g:SyQAAOSwfz9bWuF3 and 10 males for $2.84: https://www.ebay.com/itm/10-Pcs-2-Pin-DIN-Speaker-Plug-2-Pin-Plug-Hifi-Loudspeaker-Cable-Solder-Connector/323849888102?hash=item4b66f52166:g:4ysAAOSwOKlc1Pak FREE SHIPPING :) Now just have to figure out the gauge of the speaker wire to order...